# Is my reasoning for this problem about linear operators correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image]

---

Part A) The problem asks if this application of $D$ and $D^2$ is linear where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$ and $D^2=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$. I know that the 2 rules to check to see if something is a linear operator are

[image]

But I'm not confident in my answer. My reasoning is this: If $D^2$ and $D$ are linear, then simply adding them also produces a linear result. Adding a $1$ at the end doesn't change anything.

Part B) I'm not sure what the $x^2$ and the $2x$ do to the result. Actually, this one makes me wonder if my reasoning is flawed for the first part. Is the purpose of this question simply asking if the *result* is linear and **not** if the operation is linear?

Comment: Why do you say that adding a 1 at the end doesn't change anything?

Comment: @littleO I guess because I don't understand the concept well enough lol...